# nodejs deploy to Heroku and openshift get fail, but local side is work

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, openshift

I am new for nodejs and want build api from tokbox service.
I want deploy but get fail and local is normal work.
Heroku and openshift all get 503 error.
Can you help to solve the issue? thakns

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express'),
     OpenTok = require('opentok');

var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000
// var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'


// Verify that the API Key and API Secret are defined
var apiKey = "***",
    apiSecret = "*****";
if (!apiKey || !apiSecret) {
  console.log('You must specify API_KEY and API_SECRET environment variables');
  process.exit(1);
}

// Initialize the express app
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Initialize OpenTok
var opentok = new OpenTok(apiKey, apiSecret);

// Create a session and store it in the express app
opentok.createSession({ mediaMode: 'routed' },function(err, session) {
  if (err) throw err;
  app.set('sessionId', session.sessionId);
  // We will wait on starting the app until this is done
  init();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.get('/host', function(req, res) {
  var sessionId = app.get('sessionId'),
      // generate a fresh token for this client
      token = opentok.generateToken(sessionId, { role: 'moderator' });

  res.json('host.ejs', {
    apiKey: apiKey,
    sessionId: sessionId,
    token: token
  });
});

app.get('/participant', function(req, res) {
  var sessionId = app.get('sessionId'),
      // generate a fresh token for this client
      token = opentok.generateToken(sessionId, { role: 'moderator' });

  res.json('participant.ejs', {
    apiKey: apiKey,
    sessionId: sessionId,
    token: token
  });
});

app.get('/history', function(req, res) {
  var page = req.param('page') || 1,
      offset = (page - 1) * 5;
  opentok.listArchives({ offset: offset, count: 5 }, function(err, archives, count) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, 'Could not list archives. error=' + err.message);
    res.json('history.ejs', {
      archives: archives,
      showPrevious: page > 1 ? ('/history?page='+(page-1)) : null,
      showNext: (count > offset + 5) ? ('/history?page='+(page+1)) : null
    });
  });
});

app.get('/download/:archiveId', function(req, res) {
  var archiveId = req.param('archiveId');
  opentok.getArchive(archiveId, function(err, archive) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, 'Could not get archive '+archiveId+'. error='+err.message);
    res.redirect(archive.url);
  });
});

app.get('/start', function(req, res) {
  opentok.startArchive(app.get('sessionId'), {
    name: 'Node Archiving Sample App'
  }, function(err, archive) {
    if (err) return res.send(500,
      'Could not start archive for session '+sessionId+'. error='+err.message
    );
    res.json(archive);
  });
});

app.get('/stop/:archiveId', function(req, res) {
  var archiveId = req.param('archiveId');
  opentok.stopArchive(archiveId, function(err, archive) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, 'Could not stop archive '+archiveId+'. error='+err.message);
    res.json(archive);
  });
});

app.get('/delete/:archiveId', function(req, res) {
  var archiveId = req.param('archiveId');
  opentok.deleteArchive(archiveId, function(err) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, 'Could not stop archive '+archiveId+'. error='+err.message);
    res.redirect('/history');
  });
});

// Start the express app
function init() {
  app.listen(server_port, function() {
    // console.log('You\'re app is now ready at http://localhost:3000/');
     console.log( "Listening on "  + ", server_port " + server_port )
  });
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "opentok-archiving-sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Demo of OpenTok API",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cloud-env": "^0.1.0",
    "ejs": "^0.8.6",
    "express": "^3.5.0",
    "opentok": "^2.2.4",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "package.json": "0.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.32"
  }
}
```

Procfile

```
web: node index.js
```

heroku logs

```
2014-11-25T14:57:19.510550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-11-25T14:57:22.210900+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2014-11-25T14:57:23.914960+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on , server_port 3000
2014-11-25T14:58:22.632339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-11-25T14:58:22.633344+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-11-25T14:58:23.594609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-11-25T14:58:23.593810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-11-25T14:58:23.584986+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-11-25T14:58:25.481786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2014-11-25T14:58:27.589769+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on , server_port 3000
2014-11-25T14:58:45.135278+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=infinite-gorge-6020.herokuapp.com request_id=65a70579-fe23-42a8-8aca-04657ace27c5 fwd="54.91.142.166" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your Heroku logs, it seems that your are binding to port 3000 instead of the one provided  via `PORT` environmental variable (see [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#push-local-changes)). Change 4th line to this one:

```
var server_port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```